# Combining bubble chart data with line chart data from 2 API urls in ChartJS

Tags: javascript, json, api, chart.js

I'm trying to combine both datasets together in a line & bubble chart. The issue is that the dates from the bubble chart are badly misplaced to random dates rather than the ones required, although the values (Y axis) are fine.

One API url is used for stock price daily close (line chart) and the second API url is used to plot my prediction trades (bubble chart). They both use separate dates data from their own dataset, but the dates from the bubble chart are found in the line chart date range so I guess it shouldn't be a problem(?).

I'm unsure how to make the bubble chart data fit where it's respected date is within the line chart.

Below is the javascript code:

```
fetch("link_to_first_api_json")
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    const dates = data.data.map(d => d.date);
    const aaplData = data.data.map(d => d.AAPL);

    fetch("link_to_second_api_json")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        const bubbleData = data.AAPL.map(d => {
          return {
            x: new Date(d.lastDate),
            y: d.lastPrice
          };
        });

        const ctx = document.getElementById("myCharttt").getContext("2d");
        const chart = new Chart(ctx, {
          type: "line",
          data: {
            labels: dates,
            datasets: [
              {
                label: "AAPL",
                data: aaplData,
                borderColor: "red"
              },
              {
                label: "Bubble Chart",
                data: bubbleData,
                backgroundColor: "blue",
                type: "bubble"
              }
            ]
          },
          options: {
            scales: {
              xAxes: [{
                type: "time",
                time: {
                  unit: "day"
                }
              }],
              yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                  beginAtZero: true
                }
              }]
            }
          }
        });
      })
      .catch(error => console.error(error));
  })
  .catch(error => console.error(error));
```

"link_to_first_api_json" format:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "date": "2022-02-01",
            "AAPL": 147.85000610351562
        },
        {
            "date": "2022-02-02",
            "AAPL": 297.30999755859375
        },
        {
            "date": "2022-02-03",
            "AAPL": 134.51950073242188
        },
        {
            "date": "2022-02-04",
            "AAPL": 153.7884979248047
        }
    ]
}
```

"link_to_second_api_json" format:

```
{
    "AAPL": [
        {
            "lastDate": "2022-02-02",
            "lastPrice": 297.15,
        },
        {
            "lastDate": "2022-02-04",
            "lastPrice": 153.7,
        }
    ]
}
```

Obviously there are a multitude of datapoints in each JSON, these are just snippets to specify format.

HTML code is working fine, it's no issue.

Comment: For the first API, you are not converting the dates, but for the second one, you are converting them to a JS Date object via `new Date`. Did you try by keeping this consistent for both of them?